# woocommerce search results sorting

Tags: woocommerce

I have the shop page setup fine sorting by default "latest". The woocoomerce search returns the products sorted by default "Relevance". I am looking at how I can have the woocommerce search results default sorting be the "Latest" and not "Relevance".

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Are you using the API or is this a Wordpress site?

Comment: It's a wordpress site. https://wannabuyawatch.com. Thanks